# How to get sum of all selected data from bootstrap multiselect and show in anoher input?

Tags: php, jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3

I want to sum of all selected values of data-price. For ex if i select ac repair and fan repair so get the value 2100. I am using bootstrap multiselect here.

```
<div class="form-group">
 <label>Select Service</label>
 <select id="serviceid" multiple="multiple" required>
    <option data-price="1000" value="1">maintenance</option> 
    <option data-price="2000" value="2">ac repair</option>
    <option data-price="100" value="3">fan repair</option>
    <option data-price="50" value="4">cooler repair</option>    
 </select>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all thanks to all of you for help me. I waste my whole day but i get success to fetch the data. Please see this code if anyone stuck. I appreciate to all of you.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function(){
  $('#serviceid').change(function () {
    var selected = $("#serviceid option:selected");
    var sum = 0;
     selected.each(function () {
      var tsum = $(this).val(); //it gives value 
      psum = $(this).data('price'); //it gives the data-price value
      sum += Number(psum);
     });
     $('#tsum').val(sum);
    });
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the attribute value with below code,

```
var price= $('#serviceid option:selected').attr('data-price');
```

Answer (score 0):

To sum the values of all selected values of multi select drop-down, use below code ,

```
  var sum=0;
    $('#serviceid option:selected').each(function(){
         sum+=parseInt($(this).data('price'))
    })
```

Comment: hey nalin! Thanks for answer but i want to get data-price, not the value

Comment: Thanks again, but i found the better solution.